# Angular - Substitute a base component with inherited one through binding

Tags: angular

Say I have an abstract class `BaseFooComponent` and a few components that extend that base class (say `Foocomponent1`and `FooComponent2`).

Then within the template of another component `BarComponent`, I'd like to insert a `BaseFooComponent` but the correct implementation (`Foocomponent1`or `FooComponent2`) to use should be bound to a variable of type `BaseFooComponent` in `BarComponent`.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible what you are trying is like assign parent class object to child class reference

Comment: I'm loking into some kind of injection of the correct implementation of the `BaseFooComponent` within the `BarComponent` template based on a value in the ts file of the `BarComponent`.